# Read XML content

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Suppose I have an XML like:

```
<current>
  <city id="2563232" name="London">
    <coord lon="-0.13" lat="51.51">
    <country>GB</country>
    <sun rise="2017-08-17T04:23:00" set="2017-08-17T17:48:39"/>
  </city>
  <temperature value="305.15" min="305.15" max="305.15" unit="kelvin"/>
  <humidity value="25" unit="%"/>
  <pressure value="1015" unit="hPa"/>
  <wind>...</wind>
  <clouds value="0" name="clear sky"/>
  <visibility value="10000"/>
</current>
```

I am able to see the info for City and Wind in my variable "test" when debugging like i want, but I get blanks for the rest.  My code is:

```
XmlNodeList xnlNodes = OtherClass.retrieveXMLResponse(respStream);
String test = "";

foreach (XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
  test = xndNode["city"].InnerXml;
  test = xndNode["wind"].InnerXml;
  test = xndNode["temperature"].InnerXml;
  test = xndNode["humidity"].InnerXml;
  test = xndNode["pressure"].InnerXml;
  test = xndNode["clouds"].InnerXml;
  test = xndNode["visibility"].InnerXml;
}
```

I will be replacing "test" with an object later. This is the retrieveXMLResponse method:

```
public static XmlNodeList retrieveXMLResponse(Stream stream)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);

    XmlElement xelRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/current");

    return xnlNodes;
}
```

Comment: The other tag are self-closing. So there is nothing "inside" them. What would you expect by calling `InnerXML` on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no inner XML on the nodes that just contain attributes, thus the InnerXML property is blank.  Each XML node has an [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property if you would like to read the attribute values for a given node.

Comment: Cant believe I didn't see that!  Thanks, getAttribute all I needed.